# Determining the existence of an integral linear combination

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Given $x, y, r \in \mathbb{Z}$, how can you tell whether there exist two integers $a$ and $b$ such that $ax + by = r$?

That is, how do you determine whether an integral linear combination exists for $x$, $y$, and $r$?

Comment: Extended Euclidean algorithm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider $d = \gcd(x, y)$.

$$\textrm{Then} \; \frac{ax + by}{d} =\frac{r}{d}, \frac{ax + by}{d} \in \mathbb{Z}$$

If $d$ does not divide $r$, there exist no possible $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}$. If $d$ divides $r$, the solution can be found by the [Extended Euclidean Algorithm.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_euclidean_algorithm) Thanks to Ganesh for pointing me in the right direction.